# Rviz on Windows, roscore on linux server

Tags: ros, rviz, windows, win-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi community,

Did anyone succesfully run rviz on windows? It would be interesting to use visualization on a windows client..

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194416/rviz-on-windows,-roscore-on-linux-server/) by [ReiniK](https://answers.ros.org/users/1841/reinik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 84 on 2014-10-07

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Afaik, RViz does not run on Windows right now.

Popular approaches / work-arounds include using [ROSBridge](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbridge_suite) (often in combination with the [Robot Web Tools](http://robotwebtools.org/)) and [rosserial_windows](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_windows).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2016-11-20**:
Has this changed in the past two years?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-20**:
No, not really. Although [codenotes/ros_cygwin](https://github.com/codenotes/ros_cygwin) comes close when you don't have too high performance requirements. Robot Web Tools is still a nice way to get visualisations (and some interaction) onto any device with an HTML5 capable browser.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-20**:
If some of the issues are resolved, WSL on Win10 might become a way to do this (although technically it isn't really running *on Windows* then). See [Installing ROS on Ubuntu Bash in Windows 10](http://answers.ros.org/question/238646).